# mysql order by, starting with a word, then alphabetically

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a mysql query that will order my results with the titles which begins with "timberwood", starting first, then alphabetically from there onwards. Is this possible? Or do I need to somehow re-organise it in php? Here's the code I'm trying to use, but it's not ordering it the way I want..

```
SELECT *, (case when `title` like "timberwood%" then substring(title,6) else title end) as testing FROM #__downloads_items WHERE state = 1 ORDER BY testing asc
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve it:

```
Order by case when title like 'timberwood%' then 0 else 1 end asc, title asc
```

The "case when" will give a value of 0 for anything that starts with 'timberwood%' and then 1 for anything else. As this is the first thing to sort by, all 'timberwood%' results should come to the top.